# Notifications do not work

Tags: gnome

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 19.04, but all notifications don't show.

My notification list is always empty.

On Manjaro with same version of Gnome notifications worked. 
I tried Thunderbird*, Evolution and Mailspring.

*In Thunderbird, notifications appear on the desktop.

Even when I install any app, message about transaction is over are not shown in my notifications list.

I thought the issue is in gnome extensions. But disabling it didn't help.

Any ideas?